# Стилизация <datalist>

Tags: html, css, datalist

Всем привет! Будьте добры кто шарит, как стилизовать тэг datalist? Его стрелку и прочие моменты. Мне нужен именно он, не select. В интернете почему-то проблематично с информацией. Желательно конечно без js :)

Спасибо. Хорошего дня!

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.form-wrapped {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

form {
    display: block;
    width: fit-content;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
}

form input[type="text"] {
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    min-width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="main-wrapped">
        <div class="form-wrapped">
            <form>

                <label for="in-text">Город</label>
                <input id="in-text" type="text" list="citys" placeholder="Введите или выберите из списка">

                <datalist id="citys">
                    <option value="Раз">
                    <option value="Два">
                    <option value="Три">
                </datalist>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тег  просто предоставляет список данных и может использоваться с разными типами инпутов. В данном случае нужно гуглить стилизацию input[type=text].

Стрелочку в вебките можно убрать с помощью:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Например можно так:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.form-wrapped {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

form {
    display: block;
    width: fit-content;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form label {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
}


input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}

input[type=text] {
 /* styling */
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
 

  /* reset */
  
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
     
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, gray 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, gray 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #aaa, #ccc);
  background-position:
    calc(100% - 19px) calc(1em + 2px),
    calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px),
    calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size:
    5px 5px,
    5px 5px,
    1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="main-wrapped">
        <div class="form-wrapped">
            <form>

                <label for="in-text">Город</label>
                <input id="in-text" type="text" list="citys" placeholder="Введите или выберите из списка">

                <datalist id="citys">
                    <option value="Раз">
                    <option value="Два">
                    <option value="Три">
                </datalist>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```